# Mongoid single object related to multiple fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid

Is it possible to relate a single object as multiple fields? Something like this?

**Ad Model**

```
class Ad
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name

  referenced_in :ad_types, :as => :web_spec
  referenced_in :ad_types, :as => :print_spec
end
```

**AdType Model**

```
class AdType
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :shape
  field :size
  field :medium

  references_many :ads
end
```

Then reference each reference as a separate field in a form like this.

```
<%= f.input :web_spec, :collection => AdType.where(:medium => "Web"), :label_method => :shape, :label => "Web" %>
<%= f.input :print_spec, :collection => AdType.where(:medium => "Print"), :label_method => :shape, :label => "Print" %>
```

I've given something like this with no luck. I'm probably going about it the wrong way or this feature just doesn't exist yet. Any suggestions would be great appeciated.

Answer (score 0):

A few questions. Is there a reason why AdType is a document unto itself? Unless you're going to have a large number of types, it might make more sense for it to be an embedded document. Secondly, what might be cleaner is having a single association (regardless if it's referenced or embedded) and two scopes to your Ad model. Using your example, I'd have something like this:

```
class Ad
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name
  embeds_one :ad_type

  scope :web ...
  scope :print ...
end

class AdType
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :shape
  field :size
  field :medium

  embedded_in :ad, :inverse_of => :ad_type
end
```

Comment: How might you go about implementing a collection select for an embedded document? The point of the association is to enforce consistency as well as having the ability to added additional ad types.

Comment: I may be wrong but based on your reply and initial question, I believe what you want to do is an association extension (see http://mongoid.org/docs/associations/). For what it's worth, Mongoid's documentation is top notch.